# Enumeration of algebraic number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is there a way to enumerate algebraic number fields so no two listed are isomorphic? I am interested in their structure, and for quadratic fields it's simply adjoining a square root, but it looks more complicated for higher orders and I'm not sure how to enumerate them without missing any.

Comment: You can enumerate the irreducible monic polynomials  $f_i \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, test if $f_i(y)$ splits completely in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f_i(x))[y]$, in that case test if $f_{i}$ stays irreducible in the $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(g_k(x)),k\le n$, if it does set $g_{n+1} = f_i$. This way you can construct an increasing sequence of Galois extensions $K_n/\mathbb{Q}$ such that any number field is contained in some $K_n$. @DietrichBurde

Comment: Hm, yes, that sounds interesting. Thanks.

Comment: The difficult part is to test if $f_i$ stays irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(g_k(x))$, I don't know if it is really possible. Maybe you can use that testing irreducibility is easy in finite fields ?

Comment: Then, an additional question: is there anything like a canonical form of the algebraic fields, the "best" way to pick a base for each?

Comment: It might not give you the answer, but it might be illuminating for you to look at http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/ On second thought, maybe looking at that is what prompted your question in the first place?